# SpringBoot WEB-INF not loaded

Tags: java, xml, spring, servlets, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application. Packaged as a war file, such that the contents are as follows

```
static
org - springframework - boot -loader - SpringClasses
META-INF
    - MANIFEST.MF
    - maven -my.group.id - my-artifact-id - pom.xml & pom.properties
WEB-INF
    - lib (contains all jars)
    - classes (my main application's classes)
    - some other stuff
    - web.xml
    - main-servlet.xml
```

Where web.xml and main-servlet.xml are the configuration xml's

I tried, from the springBoot application doing as follows:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ImportResource({ "classpath:main-servlet.xml"})
public class FakeAppBooter {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SpringApplication.run(FakeAppBooter.class, args);
        System.out.println("Test");
    }

    public DispatcherServlet mvcDispatcherServlet() {
            XmlWebApplicationContext ctx = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
            ctx.setConfigLocation("classpath:main-servlet.xml");
            DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(ctx);
            return dispatcherServlet;
        }

        @Bean
        public ServletRegistrationBean mvcServletRegistrationBean() {
            ServletRegistrationBean bean = new ServletRegistrationBean();
            bean.setServlet(mvcDispatcherServlet());
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add("/");
            bean.setUrlMappings(list);
            return bean;
        }
}
```

However on startup I get :

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [main-servlet.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
        ... 25 more
```

I need these to define the servlets for my application.

what should I do?

Comment: WEB-INF isn't part of the classpath... NExt to that a `web.xml` is useless as Spring Boot doesn't use that. Spring Boot already adds a `DispatcherServlet` so why are you configuring one yourself... Why aren't you just using Spring Boot... Currently it looks like you are trying to work around it.

Comment: I'm converting an existing project so it would be simpler to use all the existing configuration.

Comment: That still doesn't mean you need to define your own servlet... As statedf `WEB-INF` isn't part of the classpath. Using `/WEB-INF/main-servlet` as a `@ImportResource` should be enough. I would also suggest the first thing to do is remove all the things from your configuration that Spring Boot already configures (or can configure) for you. This will drastically improve your configuration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution for your Question:**

1. While you are using SpringBoot Never care about your web.xml, Because SpringBoot itself will initialize your web Container through EmbeddedServletContainer preferably TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer. Hence ignore your web.xml configuration and it resolves your first question
2. You haven't placed your main-servlet.xml in proper classpath. Copy your main-servlet.xml and paste it in **src folder** of your project.
3. Change your code accordingly

   ```
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
   import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
   //Place your Imports Appropriately

   /**
    * @author Praveen
    *
    */
     @EnableWebMvc
     @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
     @ImportResource({ "classpath:main-servlet.xml"})
     @ComponentScan
     public class FakeAppBooter {
     private ApplicationContext ctx;
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     SpringApplication.run(FakeAppBooter.class, args);
     System.out.println("Test>>>>");
    }
     public DispatcherServlet mvcDispatcherServlet() {
        ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();
        ((AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext)                       ctx).setConfigLocation("classpath:main-servlet.xml");
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();
         return dispatcherServlet;
      }

     @Bean
       public ServletRegistrationBean mvcServletRegistrationBean() {
       ServletRegistrationBean bean = new ServletRegistrationBean();
       bean.setServlet(mvcDispatcherServlet());
       ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
       list.add("/");
       bean.setUrlMappings(list); 
       return bean;
       }
     }
   ```
4. main-servlet.xml 
   I have kept the main-servlet.xml in a very simple manner.

   [main-servlet.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEtEo.jpg)
5. **Successful Log Below**
   [Successful Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rS4qB.jpg)

Comment: Please try the above approach let me know your comments.